# Stellar failure safety with UNSAFE_QUORUM false

Tags: stellar-core, consensus, private-network

Stellar failure safety is defined as `n = 3f+1 <=> f = (n-1)/3`  `n`  is number of node and  `f` is failure safety.

I have setup 3 nodes with my quorum and `THRESHOLD_PERCENT=67` but it is not allowing my quorum.

error:

```
    2018-04-18T13:24:05.024 <startup> [default ERROR] Can't have FAILURE_SAFETY=0 unless you also set UNSAFE_QUORUM=true. Be sure you know what you are doing! [Config.cpp:596]
    2018-04-18T13:24:05.024 <startup> [default INFO]  Current QUORUM_SET breaks with 1 failures
    2018-04-18T13:24:05.024 <startup> [default FATAL] Got an exception: SCP unsafe [main.cpp:917]
```

din't get exactly what is wrong, any explanation? `FAILURE_SAFETY is set to default -1.`

Answer (score 2):

It says `Can't have FAILURE_SAFETY=0 unless you also set UNSAFE_QUORUM=true`. I guess you might have set somewhere FAILURE_SAFETY=0.

[In the example config](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L194), it says

> A value of 0 is only allowed if UNSAFE_QUORUM is set

Therefore, your log showed `Got an exception: SCP unsafe`. To fix this, you have to declare `UNSAFE_QUORUM=true`.

---

As you have 3 nodes, n=3 <=> f<1.

Less than 1 node can malfunction while the consensus network still works, i.e. Your network can tolerate ZERO node to malfunction.

It makes sense for you to put FAILURE_SAFETY=0, but you also have to set UNSAFE_QUORUM=true.

```
FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
```

Comment: default `FAILURE_SAFETY` is -1, so in my case this calculate `f<1`, if i don't put `FAILURE_SAFETY` in my config this auto assume `FAILURE_SAFETY` to zero ?

Comment: No, the default value is -1. If you don't modify it explicitly, `FAILURE_SAFETY` takes the default -1. The value always assumes it is -1; it won't change to zero automatically.